# Cannot open SharePoint 2010 Package in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2010

I tried to use visual studio 2012 to develop SharePoint 2010 solution on TFS 2012, i created the project on my Machine & add it to TFS. but when one of my team get latest version and check in the solution,anyone tried get latest version and open the package get the below error(Appear in Huge Message box):

---

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.

1) Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Resulting in: An exception occurred while calling the 'OnImportsSatisfied' method on type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package.ViewModels.PackageViewModel'.

Resulting in: Cannot activate part 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package.ViewModels.PackageViewModel'.

Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package.ViewModels.PackageViewModel -->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package.ViewModels.PackageViewModel -->  AssemblyCatalog (Assembly="Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")

Resulting in: Cannot get export 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package.ViewModels.PackageViewModel (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package.ViewModels.IPackageViewModel")' from part 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package.ViewModels.PackageViewModel'.

Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package.ViewModels.PackageViewModel (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package.ViewModels.IPackageViewModel") -->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package.ViewModels.PackageViewModel -->  AssemblyCatalog (Assembly="Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")

Resulting in: Cannot set import 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package.ViewProviders.PackageDesignViewProvider.ViewModel (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package.ViewModels.IPackageViewModel")' on part 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package.ViewProviders.PackageDesignViewProvider'.

Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package.ViewProviders.PackageDesignViewProvider.ViewModel (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package.ViewModels.IPackageViewModel") -->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package.ViewProviders.PackageDesignViewProvider -->  AssemblyCatalog (Assembly="Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")

Resulting in: Cannot get export 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package.ViewProviders.PackageDesignViewProvider (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package.ViewProviders.IViewProvider")' from part 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package.ViewProviders.PackageDesignViewProvider'.

Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package.ViewProviders.PackageDesignViewProvider (ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package.ViewProviders.IViewProvider") -->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package.ViewProviders.PackageDesignViewProvider -->  AssemblyCatalog (Assembly="Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")

Resulting in: An exception occurred while calling the 'OnImportsSatisfied' method on type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package.Hosts.DslHost`1[[Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Models.Packages.Package, Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Models.Packages, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]]'.

Resulting in: Cannot activate part 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package.Hosts.DslHost(Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Models.Packages.Package)'.

Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package.Hosts.DslHost(Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Models.Packages.Package) -->  Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Package.Hosts.DslHost(Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Models.Packages.Package)

---

### OK

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it , this error coming when visual studio try to get assemblies from GAC related to SharePoint package designer, Just Install "**Office Developer Tool for visual studio**" via Microsoft web platform installer or visual studio, it will work

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't create SharePoint 2010 solutions (package WSP) with VS2012 coz 2012 tools supports only SP2013 (csproj and project structure are very similar though).

You probably can build dll (library) with VS2012 and SP2010 referenced dlls and than use [wspbuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/)
to create wsp targeting SP2013 (good compatibility with SP2013, will be deployed to 2010 hive).

Comment: The project is working on SharePoint 2010 good & deploy success  every time no runtime error.

Comment: Yes, but i cannot add feature to package